# Jackson Mapper and Java Mapping

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I've a problem when I try to map a JSON file to a Object with Jackson Library, I've tried a lot of things but it still doesn't work.

This is my JSON file:

```
{
2: {
    1: {
        cuota: "25092.87",
        var12m: "-4.01",
        var1m: "4.23"
    },
    2: {
        cuota: "23319.83",
        var12m: "-0.63",
        var1m: "3.33"
    },
    3: {
        ....
    }
},
3: { ..... }
```

My Object in Java is this:

```
public class AfpsDetalles {

private String key;
private HashMap<Integer, Fondos> fondos = new HashMap<Integer, Fondos>();

public static class Fondos{
    private float cuota;
    private float var12m;
    private float var1m;
}
}
```

And when I map the object I use this:

```
HashMap<Integer,AfpsDetalles> afpDetalle = mapper.readValue(JSON FILE, new TypeReference<HashMap<Integer,AfpsDetalles>>() {});
```

Jackson error said that is a problem with the first "1". Please any help will be apprecied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not valid JSON. JSON property names must be Strings, and Strings are surrounded in double-quotes. So first thing is to fix this problem.